# Can plasma under ANY circumstances get attracted to a magnet?

Tags: plasma-physics

Can plasma under ANY circumstances get attracted to a magnet? y/n If so, then under what circumstances?

Comment: related  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238361/

Comment: Charged particles in a magnetic field obey the Lorentz force.  The Earth is basically a big dipole bar magnet and particles respond to its field just as you would expect from the Lorentz force.  It's not really that particles are "attracted" to a magnetic like iron filings.  They respond to it because it applies a force, but the force is orthogonal to both the field and the particle velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particles in a plasma can have a magnetic dipole moment (nuclear or electronic). A magnetic dipole experiences a force in a diverging magnetic field.

So the short answer appears to be "yes" - in a diverging field, a plasma will experience some attraction.

Whether that force is ever stronger than the other forces in the plasma is not something that can easily be answered - but then you didn't ask.